# Rails - User.count didn't change by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My personal website is being built on rails but I'm stuck with the User.count for the login area not updating. Been sitting with this for a day trying to get it to work but no luck so far. I've included all the code if someone could spot my error as I can't see it.

```
 class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @user = users(:one)
    @input_attributes = {
      name: 'luchia',
      password: 'secret',
      password_confirmation: 'secret' 
    }
  end

  test "should create user" do
   assert_difference('User.count') do
    post :create, user: @input_attributes
  end
  assert_redirected_to users_path
  end
```

Then there is my User Controller

```
 # GET /users/1
 # GET /users/1.json
 def show
 end

 # GET /users/new
 def new
  @user = User.new
 end

 # GET /users/1/edit
 def edit
 end

 # POST /users
 # POST /users.json
 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "User #{@user.name} was successfully created." }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

And my Terminal error:

```
$ rake test
Run options: --seed 11633

# Running tests:

....[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If   you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
....................F......

Finished tests in 1.143021s, 27.1211 tests/s, 45.4935 assertions/s.

1) Failure:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_create_user [/Users/lucybloomfield/Documents/luchia /test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:25]:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 3
Actual: 2

31 tests, 52 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Would appreciate anyone's help.

////////////////

Mmkay, this is what I ended up coming up with but it's not very concise. Rake test is completing with this so I guess it will have to do.

```
  test "should create user" do
   assert_difference('User.count') do
    post :create, {:user => {'name' => 'luchia', 'password' => 'secret', 'password_confirmation' => 'secret'}}
    .to change(User, :count).by(1)
   end
   assert_redirected_to users_path
  end
```

//////////////

Edit again, the above bit of code fails on the second rake test.

Answer (score 0):

Example with capybara and cucumber

```
describe "new" do
            before do 
                    visit new_user_path
            end

            it { should have_title(I18n.t("user.new")) }

            describe "with invalid information" do
                    before { find("form#new_user").submit_form! }

                    it { should have_title(I18n.t("user.new")) }
                    it { should have_selector("div#alerts") }
            end

            describe "with valid information" do
                    before do
                            fill_in "user_name", :with => "user_name"
                            fill_in "user_email", :with => "user@example.com"
                            fill_in "user_password", :with => "123456"
                            fill_in "user_password_confirmation", :with => "123456"
                            find("form#new_user").submit_form!
                    end

                    it { should have_content(I18n.t("user.success"))}
            end
    end
```

Comment: Just tried but no luck, same error when running the rake test.

Comment: @user = users(:one) in that line, the user variable ends up beign a valid user?

Comment: a little offtopic, but You can do those kinds of tests with capybara an factoryGirl, I have updated my answer and let you my user tests so you get an example of how would look like with FactoryGirl and Capybara, Have a nice one!

Comment: Argh, would you believe it's not working again. It works on the first rake test but not the second.

Comment: I hadn't, I'm pretty new to Rails. Working through the Agile Web development with Rails 4 and applying what I learn. What are the benefits?

Comment: that you can create instances of your Models and use the instances to test the behavior that your app it's supposed to have. However in my answer I used capybara, not FactoryGirl, capybara let you test the DOM very easily as you can see in the example I submit an invalid user and it's expected to fail, and a valid user that it's expected to be saved

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a

```
puts YAML::dump(@user.save!)
```

in your method create of `UsersControlller`

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  puts YAML::dump(@user.save!)
...
end
```

To see why it doesn't save.
Then check your `user_params` permit if it necessary

Answer (score 0):

set

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
```

to your config/application.rb

inside as exampled:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
  end
end
```

and restart server